# Javascript cookie to store radio button arrays

Tags: javascript, cookies, radio-button

I have a javascript cookie which sets a default value of NYY (no, yes, yes) when a user enters the site. Bascially i need to be able to change this default value when a user selects from a list of 3 choices (radio or checkbox) from another page and remember his settings.

Here's my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function createCookie(name,value,days) {
if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();

}
else var expires = "";
document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
var nameEQ = name + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
}

return null;
}

function printCookies(w){
cStr = "";
pCOOKIES = new Array();
pCOOKIES = document.cookie.split('; ');
for(bb = 0; bb < pCOOKIES.length; bb++){
    NmeVal  = new Array();
    NmeVal  = pCOOKIES[bb].split('=');
    if(NmeVal[0]){
        cStr += NmeVal[0] + '=' + unescape(NmeVal[1]) + '; ';
    }
}
return cStr;
}


function eraseCookie(name) {
createCookie(name,"",-1);
}

function setTheDivStyle() {
if(!readCookie('preference')) {
// if cookie not found display the div and create the cookie
document.getElementById("prefBanner").style.display="block";
/*document.getElementById("prefBanner").style.display="block";*/
createCookie('preference', 'NYY', 365);  // 365 day
}
else {
// if cookie found hide the div
document.getElementById("prefBanner").style.display="none";
}
}

// print all cookies set for the domain
allCookies = printCookies();
//document.write(allCookies);
alert(allCookies);
</script>



<body onload="setTheDivStyle();" onclick="setTheDivStyle();">
<div id = "prefBanner" class="prefCookie_banner">cookie policy banner - which the users sees if no cookie is set - to change your cookie preference <a href="newpage">click here</a></div>
```

**Newpage: where i want to change the default value of the cookie**

```
<FORM NAME="profileForm">
Performance
<input type="radio" value="Y" id="performance" name="performance"><label     for="performance"> Yes</label>
<input type="radio" value="N" id="performance" name="performance"><label   for="performance"> No</label><br />
```

Functional
     Yes
     No

```
Tracking
<input type="radio" value="Y" id="tracking" name="tracking"><label for="tracking"> Yes</label>
   <input type="radio" value="N" id="tracking" name="tracking"><label for="tracking">     No</label><br />

<input type="submit" >


</FORM>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this will work but I will not do it that way but looking at the code and the formulated question this is the best answer.

```
<input type="radio" value="Y" id="trackingY" name="tracking" onclick="createCookie('preference', 'Y', 365);">

<input type="radio" value="N" id="trackingN" name="tracking" onclick="createCookie('preference', 'N', 365);">
```

There are some horrible mistake in your code sorry to be direct but if you continue like this it's going to be tough to write bigger function.

1. The HTML is not valid: an ID is a unique identifier this mean that only 1 element can have the same id.
2. Use the curly brace where they should go
3. use the var to declare your variable
4. The split function return an array why declaring a new array on the variable before the split

   pCOOKIES = new Array();

   pCOOKIES = document.cookie.split('; ');